DRV8835 motor kickback affecting quadrature encoder
I am trying to use a quadrature encoder with some DFRobot DC motors on my custom PCB. They work fine at low speeds, but at high speeds they don't work (count each others ticks, etc). I was very confused by this because originally I though the encoders (there are 2) were interfering with each other, but after a lot of testing with my new oscilloscope I think it is caused by some weird spikes in the motor.
In the following pictures, the yellow line is showing one of the motor pins and the blue line is showing an Encoder A pin. I created these images by spinning the motor by hand very quickly and using a trigger on the motor pin.

In this image, you can see the fast spikes in the motor are causing the encoder to trigger the MCU's external interrupt.

This is a zoomed in image of the spike in the motor itself, it is very noisy.

This is a sort of zoomed out image.
Here is the PCB design:

As you can see the encoder pins are going somewhat close to the motor traces, but even the closest traces (the ones I have selected in the image) are still >0.5mm apart.
I re-designed my circuit board so that the traces are further away:

Schematic for motor driver:

Schematic for encoders (E1A/E2A/E1B/E2B go to MCU):

I haven't ordered it since I'm not sure if this is enough. Is it? Is there something else going on? Is this even inductive kickback? Do I need to add some components to prevent the motor spikes from affecting the encoders? Do I just need to keep the traces further away? I have never been taught about this kind of thing so I'm not sure. Thanks for your help!

Please post a schematic; don't make us reverse engineer your PCB.

Please with the schematic! Also, I wrote calibration software for critical medical devices -- a whole experience by itself -- with infusion pumps running anywhere up to 250 rpm with 512 A and 512 B pulses per revolution, and a home pulse. Calibration involved  gently adjusting the optical quadrature unit while observing data in real time before applying a superglue to lock things up. No problems. Nothing like what i see there. Need schematic to have any hope. What's your max speed and other details?

Ah sorry, I have updated the post to include the schematic!

@Nv7 You will need to use my name if you expect me to see the message. I just saw it now because I randomly went here. Appears you write that once the motors are removed the problem goes away. How are you testing the varying speeds without motors -- another way of running the encoders up to speed?

@periblepsis Yes, I spin the motors by hand

I re-designed the board so that the traces were far apart and made sure the cables were far apart. Unfortunately, that still didn't fix this electrically.
Using an Input Filter of 10 in the STM32 Timer Encoder mode made the problem go away though.

You should include a schematic.
That said, the spikes you are seeing are unlikely to be read by your MCU simply due to proximity of the traces, unless your MCU has a really low logic level high threshold.
These are what I would suggest you check for:

make sure you have diodes on the motor lines to discharge any backemf into the supply rails.
keep your power supplies for the digital circuits and power circuits separate. Even if they're originating from the same source, treat them separately and add extra bulk decoupling capacitors at the point at which they diverge.
ensure that your digital ICs are well decoupled from any supply noise. This applies to your MCU as well as your encoder,and any other logic ICs handling the signal.
you may want to separate your power ground and your digital ground. They can still be coming from the same supply, but joined together at a place where switching transients (or more correctly, the return currents of switching transients) don't disturb the digital circuits. An easy place to do this which might work for you is near the input of the power supply to your pcb. The ideal place would be somewhere close to where your digital lines interact with your power circuits.

I've found that the most reliable (though not nearly cheapest) way to avoid this problem is to use a separate power supply for the motors and galvanically isolate the digital signals. This is especially true for motors drawing multiple amps which you're trying to control with a high frequency PWM.

I found that the spikes are >1.3V (in the picture you can see its over that), so I think it is possible that they are triggering the MCU (STM32). I am using raw battery VIN for the motors and using a switching voltage regulator to power the MCU. I believe the DRV8835 has diodes? Do you think just spacing out the traces as shown in my followup image will work?

I generally add additional diodes externally as well.

Spacing out the traces is unlikely to work. That only reduces the effect if the signals are radiatively coupled. Since you're probably at sub 100kHz, unless your traces are very long and running parallel, 1.3V of signal on an adjacent line is very, very high to be likely. More likely, your spikes are also showing up on the ground or power supply. This is a conductive coupling between the two circuits which makes the effective signal voltage relative to ground at that point drop.

Do you have a 4 layer pcb? If not, can you make a separate picture of your bottom layer, not that you have a ground layer split somewhere

I tried un-plugging the motors from the PCB and the encoders worked, so I think that it is a problem with the PCB.
The ground plane on the old design had a split in it but the new design doesn't.

You need the split in the ground plane.
